# Cannot Remove Write Protection From My USB Drive

Tags: windows-7, usb, write-protect

Today, one of my long used USB pen drive suddenly become write protected. Whenever I try to save or copy a file to it, it will popup and says "the disk is write protected".

So, I did some googling and try to remove write protection with `attributes disk clear readonly`. But the problem is, it seems to be doesn't remove the read only state and I am still unable to write file to my USB drive.

```
DISKPART> attributes disk clear readonly

Disk attributes cleared successfully.

DISKPART> attributes disk
Current Read-only State : Yes
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Take a look: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-fix-write-protection-errors-on-a-usb-stick/ especially Step 6 – Into the Registry We Go

Comment: Means it might be dying - make sure there's nothing important on there.

Comment: Dupe: [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/q/1125282) (I'm out of close votes)