# Can't format the fat32 sd card, Bad FAT: unterminated chain

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, sd-card

I'm trying to format this SD Card, and gParted says all operations successful but when the devices refresh the data is still there hence the disk is unformatted.

When I perform the "Check" operation on the partition it gives me **Bad FAT: unterminated chain** error so I suppose it is the reason why I can't format the drive.
I can't delete the partition can't resize the partition and can't perform any of the such operations.

Below is the screenshot of the exact error.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried running `dosfsck` or `scandisk` like it tells you to in the error message?

Comment: I have did not do the trick

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only