# How to force formatting for micro SD card that are marked at filesystem level as read only?

Tags: linux, partitioning, formatting, sd-card

**BACKGROUND**
I formatted a mini SD card with FAT filesystem, placed some files on it. Placed into a kids toy (Landzo) and when I removed the card the whole SD was marked as read-only by the firmware of the toy. I tried a million of the most common things and I don't seem to be able to make the card RW again.

**PROBLEM**
I can't format the card nor edit its content. I want to format and as a bonus, it would be awesome to know what the heck goes on... It's a mini SD so there's no pin to flip on the physical device.

**WHAT I KNOW**
This is what the structure looks like
[image: diskutil list]

**WHAT I TRIED**

I tried to change the permissions (chown) on the card since the info card shows that it is read only. No errors but also no change. I tried on the volume and the disk. Didn't do anything.
[image: Volume info]

Then I tried

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume exFAT MYSD MBRFormat /dev/disk2s1
```

I tried volume and then the disk option and I received back the same annoying error:

> **Couldn’t open device. : (-69877)**

When I tried other exoteric things I received back the consistent error that the car is not writeable.

It's a mini sd there's no switch, the table/partition has been modified and clearly, it is fooling the standard commands. I am OK in losing all content, I just want a way to gain back the card for further tries on what I was trying to do in the first place :-)

I also tried from windows with Diskpart which went a little further and also on a Ubuntu machine. Nada!!!

Tried another [zillion](https://superuser.com/questions/1163341/micro-sd-overlapped-to-locked-and-read-only-state-how-to-fix-it) of things based on an extensive search on StackOverflow and other venues. I am at a loss...

Help!

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313845/disk-utility-cannot-erase-usb-drive-error-69877-couldnt-open-device - is the SD to MicroSD adapter perhaps flipped to 'write protect'?

Comment: as mentioned in the post it is a micro SD, there's no hardware to switch. It is a file system issue.

Comment: The post refers to an SD sized adapter to fit said MicroSD into a regular SD slot, these come with the same switch. You did not mention which kind of slot your MicroSD has been fitted into in your post.