# what programmatic changes makes the usb drive write protected

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, disk-encryption, write-protect

suddenly 32 GB sandisk pen-drive has become write protected, i want to know what makes the pen drive write protected, so that it I can figure out what is the right solution to make it work again.

Thanks

Comment: Technically, this question is not a duplicate - OP asks about the mechanism of flash drive being "write protected". An attempt of answering in right direction is given here, http://superuser.com/a/1164295/620011

Comment: @mokubai question is not duplicate i dont want writ protection solution, i want to know why it gets write protection, what changes on flash drive makes it write protected

Comment: @Ali Chen the given answer gives some direction to my question, but still require more information

Comment: I don't have any more information. The embedded system is proprietary and Sandisk does not disclose any information. Throw the pen drive away, and forget it.