# Flash drive bricked file system

Tags: usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I repaired my 32gb flash drive with UP tool.
Then i try convert the file system to NTFS using EaseUs.
My flash drive broken after convert to NTFS with EaseUs partition wizard.
The file system being "unknown" and showing 0mb space.
There is 32gb unlocated space showing in disk management and its unusable. 
Tried to use diskpart.
Tried a lot of tools.
UP tool wont detect phison ps2251-68 after using EaseUs.
Any solution?

Comment: What was wrong with it before you 'repaired' it? Did you ever test it was a real 32GB or a fake? Also see - http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only

Comment: Can you clarify the "to what?" question associated with "Any solution?"?  Are you trying to recover data from it?  Make it usable again?  You say this all started when you repaired it.  What was the problem you repaired?

Answer (score 0):

You could buy a new one for under $10

https://www.amazon.com/USB-Flash-Drives-32GB-Data-Storage

It sounds like the one you have is broken.

Comment: I have so far seen two bricked flash drives and managed to use a software fix which I posted in an answer to unbrick both of them. On the other hand linking to the question I answered as a duplicate question has taught me 1. My software fix often does not work. and 2. Try the simple solutions before the complicated ones.