# MicroSD card write protected, cannot unlock (tried on different computers, different adapters)

Tags: micro-sd-card, write-protect

I am on read only on my microSD card, that previously I was able to read/write on. I've tried using different adapters, tried locking then unlocking those adapters (as well as putting the toggle in the middle), I've also tried reading the card on different computers, to no success. I've also tried to "overwrite" on the SDFormatter app (that I previously used when I was able to edit the card), but the SDFormatter also says that they cannot make changes unless the write protection is off. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: duplicate: https://superuser.com/a/1125283/707676

Answer (score -1):

If You Have linux Base System You Can Use This Command To Make Sure All Your Data Wiped And All Atributes Will Remove From Your Sd-card

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/{your device name} bs=4k status=transfer