# How to make a USB stick with iso9660 filesystem writeable again?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, filesystems, mount, iso-image

I used the Startup Disk Creator to make a bootable USB stick and now it can only be mounted read-only.

Output of `sudo mount /media/user/Volume_Label/ -o remount,rw`:

```
mount: cannot remount /dev/sdb1 read-write, is write-protected
```

Output of `mount` command:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/user/Volume_Label type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Output of `dmesg` command:

```
[108080.964308]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[108080.966929] sd 12:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[108093.023957] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[108093.026207] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[108093.027453] ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
```

How do I make this USB stick writeable again?

Comment: Also note that the drive is currently split into two partitions. You might want to reverse that, using your favorite partition manager.

Comment: @DanielB mkfs.vfat -I created a partition on the entire drive

Comment: `mkfs.vfat` does not modify partitions. You just created the filesystem *without* any partitions. That’s also valid and supported on USB thumb drives, even on Windows.

Comment: Same for me. Using Startup disk creator is a big mistake.

Answer (score 4):

You can't write to a medium formatted with the ISO 9660 filesystem because it is a filesystem designed for CD's/DVD's and therefore it isn't capable of write operations.
ISO 13490 is a extension of ISO 9660 which adds write support.

**Wikipedia excerpt:**

> Since ISO 9660 is by design a read-only, pre-mastered file system, all
>   the data has to be written in one go or "session" to the medium. Once
>   written, there is no provision for altering the stored content. ISO
>   13490 was created to allow adding more files to a writeable disc such
>   as CD-R in multiple sessions.

To erase the USB stick and format it with a write supporting filesystem you can use `sudo mkfs.vfat -I /dev/sdb` (the `-I` tells mkfs to utilize the entire volume). Also refer to my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1233429/cannot-remove-micro-sd-cards-read-only-attribute-after-ubuntu-image/1233468#1233468).