# Corrupt USB Stick without partition table, cannot format it

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb

## What I did

I tried installing Debian on my USB stick, and it got stuck with an error in mid-process. Since then, I am not able to format the drive anymore or to mount it.

Apparently, the drive has no partitions and no partition table and nothing to work with.

## What still works

When launching GParted, it sometimes still shows the correct last file system used with the (probably) correct amount of used space. I can still write it using raw commands like cp and dd (tested with cp and a Debian live .iso file)

## What I tried

I tried all kind of checks, repairs and formatting operations on Windows and Linux with all kind of tools.

- Windows format: "Windows was unable to complete the formatting"
- Diskpart `clean`: "DiskPart has encountered an error: The system cannot find the file specified."
- Disk Management: "The system cannot find the file specified."
- GParted system check: "/dev/sdc: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
  e2fsck 1.43.5 (04-Aug-2017)e2fsck: No such device or address while trying to re-open /dev/sdc"
- GParted format to ext4: "Create new ext4 file system  00:00:00    ( ERROR ) mkfs.ext4 -F -L "" /dev/sdb  00:00:00    ( ERROR ) mke2fs 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017) The file /dev/sdb does not exist and no size was specified. libparted messages    ( INFO ) Input/output error during write on /dev/sdb Input/output error during write on /dev/sdb Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb: Input/output error Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb: Input/output error"
- I tried a lot of other tools but the didn't provide any useful error messages

Comment: Bin it & buy a new one. They're not worth fighting once they start to fail. If there's a write error, the firmware protect can kick in & render it useless. See http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only

Comment: @Tetsujin I'll do that if I can't fix it until the shops open again. The thing is I don't think it's broken since I can still write data to it and reading also kinda works. I really think it's only the file system that's corrupt, not the device.

Comment: I get through hundreds, if not thousands of these things for work. Golden rule: don't bother fighting it. You do & 2 days later you've a 120 mile call-out cos it failed again. Not worth it.

Comment: As @Tetsujin has said, likely the stick has a hardware failure (controller got confused for some reason). You can get more meaningful error messages with `dmesg` under Linux, likely you'll see USB errors, or the stick will disappear while writing to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)