# hasleo Win Setup From USB tool Destroyed my usb?

Tags: usb, formatting, mbr, diskpart

I launched the tool normally then selected the win 10 iso file then the tool asked me to select from MBR for bios - GPT for UEFI  - MBR for bios and UEFI
i have selected MBR for bios and UEFI  and clicked yes then it  started formatting then it started creating the windows to go disk after hours it finished ... after  a while i have formatted .. but then tried to copy files to it but failed ...  then i formatted  it again but it failed .. 
i tried several fixes but non worked

1-disk part

2- low level format tool

3- kingston format tool

4- MiniTool Partition

5- tried the firmware thing but it didn't appear in the tool at all

usb model : kingston usb 3.0 datatraveler 100 g3 32GB[image]

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjSvb.png)

[image]

Comment: USB Flash drives are cheap, unreliable & disposable. If one errors, discard & replace. They are not worth fighting once they go wrong. [or see http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only ]

Comment: so no fix for this one .... i have got it only 2 months ago ..... i thought it will be fixable by the firmware thing but it didn't show up...........
ok thanks for replying

Answer (score 1):

It seems that USB sticks break more likely when put unter stress, like writing a full ISO having a size of full operating system.

That's why people like to complain about the Rufus tool as destroyer of their storage.

It could be a fake stick as well that breaks after reaching a certain memory boundary. Always use h2testw to test your new drives.

Comment: No it's not a fake stick as i got it from a certified store, Kingstone replaced it for me anyway. so shout out to them , Also Rufus never killed a usb drive for me at all , I doubt this has something to do with their "Portable Windows creator" thing. Whatever , the usb wasn't that good anyway : )