# USB flash drive clearing attributes

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I was having a problem with my USB flash drive that it had become write protected. I used this drive on my friends PC. Maybe virus on his PC created this problem on my flash drive.
**Now the main problem that I am facing is that** I am trying to remove that attributes using cmd but it is not working because this can be done only on the same computer from which these (write-protection)attributes were added.
Now,

### **Can I remove write-protection(or any attributes) from a PC other than that from which these attributes were added?**

*If yes than please help me in this case and explain me the procedure!*
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for a USB device to become read-only.

You should first check for the existence of some switch on the disk that may have
put it into read-only mode.

To clear this attribute, start a Command Prompt (cmd) run as Administrator,
and enter the following commands:

```
DISKPART
LIST VOLUME
SELECT VOLUME X   (X is the number of the USB volume)
ATTRIBUTES DISK clear readonly
EXIT
```

If this doesn't help, try to format the disk.

Comment: Can't format as well as these commands don't work

Comment: Why can it only be done on your friend's computer? There should be no difference.