# Minimal Linux live system with GUI to edit root files on a USB drive

Tags: linux, usb

It seems I have a very specific problem nobody has thought about. I've set up a Raspberry Pi with an SD card and it doesn't work properly. So I need to change some of its files from a different computer. While I can plug this SD card in any computer, unfortunately it uses some Linux filesystem that cannot be accessed on Windows or Android. I only have Windows and Android devices around, nothing with Linux or macOS. The free efforts in Linux filesystem drivers for Windows all fail in Win 10 x64. So I guess I need a simple Linux desktop system that I can run in VMware.

I've already tried with Ubuntu 18.04, and while I can browse the SD card, I cannot edit anything on it because it doesn't let me access root's files. Efforts with `sudo` and the sorts have led nowhere but to errors. The default file explorer hides the mount path so a terminal won't help either.

Is there a minimal Linux system that I can run from an image, without installation, to edit those root files on the SD card with a GUI editor? I can't remember terminal commands for long so I need a GUI solution for this type of task.

Comment: This task should be possible from *any* Linux live media, including installers that can work as such (e.g. Ubuntu installer). All your problems *may* root from the SD card [going read-only](https://superuser.com/q/1125282/432690), which is not an uncommon scenario. We could say more if you posted these "efforts with `sudo` and the sorts" and "errors" they led to.

Comment: On any Linux live system I think 'sudo su' should drop you in a root shell w/o questions asked.

Comment: Here's screenshots of the errors: https://imgur.com/a/OyqeU0e In a second try, I was lucky to get a working window and could actually edit and save the file. But the file was barely visible in the tiny view of the huge and non-resizable file browser. Seems nobody expects the small screen size that is set (and not changeable) in the live system.