# USB Flash Drive won't let me format or delete files (Windows 10) after being plugged into OSX

Tags: windows-10, usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I seem to be having an issue with my USB Flash Drive that I can't seem to figure out. I deleted some files off my flash drive and this worked fine and passed it to my girlfriend to use on her Mac to transfer some photos. In the process of transferring photos something happened and the USB drive kept freezing her mac osx.

I took the drive to windows 10 and attempted to format, but keep receiving the error message "Windows unable to complete the format".

I checked the disk attributes, and it says

```
Current Read-only State : No 
Read-only  : No 
Boot Disk  : No 
Pagefile Disk  : No 
Hibernation File Disk  : No 
Crashdump Disk  : No 
Clustered Disk  : No
```

I attempted do clean the drive using diskpart utility in command prompt, but it states that it can't because of I/O errors.

I attempted to do a chkdsk on the drive, but it states there are no errors or issues.

I have attempted to use EaseUS to format the drive, it states that there was errors during formatting (nothing specific). I tried checking filesystem with EaseUS aswell and it states everything is OK.

Checking the volumes on diskpart shows the volume is "healthy"

I attempted to clear read-only using diskpart tool, but no luck. The drive contains no read-only switch. The drive does not at all indicate it is read-only. I have checked registry as well and don't see any issues.

I am able to access the files okay, I can open them on the drive, but I am unable to delete them. If I delete them, they show as deleted, but once I unplug my drive and plug it back in, they reappear. Same thing happens when I try to create a folder, it appears as though the folder was created, but once I unplug it and replug it back in, the folder no longer exists.

Windows 10 allows me to get into the format screen if I choose NTFS instead of exFAT but then it just hangs and no progress is made when formatting.

When choosing properties on the drive --> tools --> error checking, this also just hangs once it reaches to the end.

Not sure what to do here to salvage my USB flash drive. If anyone could help I would be greatly appreciative.

Thank you

Comment: Probably defective now.

Comment: Add the SMART data of the disk to the post (if the disk supports SMART).

Comment: I don't think USB flash drive supports SMART

Comment: USB itself doesn't support SMART, even if the drive does. tbh, as soon as a SD card/flash drive starts to play up, bin it. They're not worth fighting once they start to go bad. A write error will lock the firmware into read-only mode, from which there is no return at consumer level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)

Comment: Drive does not indicate that its read-only (checked using diskpart tool), checked registry aswell and don't see any write protection issues.