# Android: "Corrupted" MicroSD reads/writes fine in my laptop, but can't be formatted

Tags: linux, partitioning, android, formatting, exfat

I was moving some files to my Android phone's MicroSD, and suddenly the file system became read-only. I put the card into my Linux laptop and it mounted fine. I can read and write to it, no problem.

However, I can't delete or format the partition, using Gparted, mkfs, gnome-disks or anything else. It will think it's formatted the card, but it will immediately show up again with the old filesystem (exfat).

And the Android won't recognize the card, which it says is corrupted, and formatting in the phone fails. So what can I do?

Comment: Double-check you can actually write & format too in nix; eject & re-insert afterwards.

Comment: I'm confused by this response. I mentioned that I can write in nix, but formatting doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, misread, thought you meant the droid - anyway, see [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only) Bin the card & get a new one, in short; the firmware write protect has probably triggered, which is to all intents & purposes irreversible.

Comment: OK, this is not a duplicate question. The card is **not** read-only or write-protected. I can write to it just fine, on my laptop.

Comment: Then if it's only related to the droid, it's off-topic on here, see https://android.stackexchange.com instead

Comment: It's not only related to the droid. I said that the computer can't format the card. Read my question this time before before you mark it or comment on it.