# The trouble with access to USB Flash

Tags: usb

My friend gave me a USB so that I could fix the problem, but I can’t do anything. I read a lot of topics/articles and forums in various ways, I watched YouTube videos to find a solution to fix this problem, but nothing helped. Here is my configuration:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mtn7YTR92Q8qU9iQedBpbBBtRa3CJe9L/view?usp=drivesdk
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aI13F0e2_efpY3747y3PIPcT56RdH2ST/view?usp=drivesdk
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nynfTxN8uykattge3Xh0XofQ5zijLYKJ/view?usp=drivesdk
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i8ICQv4Snd511ZjUopfrQ5tlJ-DS8sEM/view?usp=drivesdk
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19mKmr5E0MIyVNP-SdXx6B3irKRC-kuMZ/view?usp=drivesdk
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sklhb-0IOQZcAQILGO6lW2JEbImPuHv4/view?usp=drivesdk

Also, USB is offline and I can make in Active

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jDHMss-hSRB2aWI8bMCy9kbH-4DrNZAj/view?usp=drivesdk

At that moment, when my friend brought me a USB - I can view the files, but could not transfer data. After I made the actions mentioned in the articles - USB has become what you see now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)

Comment: This is not duplicate. Before claiming, read my problem.

Comment: I read your problem, which is why I think it's a duplicate.  Can you be more specific as to why you think it isn't?