# USB Flash Drive shows 0 byte of 1.38 and nothing is in the USB drive

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, floppy

My flash drive become empty and shows empty, yas, nothing. yesterday it  worked fine but now it shows like a floppy and shows "0 bytes free of 1.38 MB" and "This folder is empty." my laptop still recognises that it's a "USB Drive" even though it's acting like a floppy disk. could you please tell me a solution to this problem?

Comment: This probably falls under http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only but the usual answer is throw it away & use another.

Comment: 0 bytes free of "X" means it's full, not empty, and 1.38 MB could be a small partition, so it isn't clear what's going on.  If you use partitioning software to wipe it and create a single partition filling the drive, formatted FAT32, any OS should recognize it.  If that doesn't work, the drive is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Some USB keys have been found to have various partition table set-ups that the USB software will not work with. You can use Windows Diskpart to re-format a USB key and re-partition it.

```
->Open a Command Window (cmd)
->Enter diskpart
->Enter list disk (it is important you KNOW which disk is the USB key you are formatting)
->Enter select disk x where x is your USB key (its mostly disk 1 if you only have a hdd)
->Enter clean
->Enter create part primary
->Enter select part 1
->Enter active
->Enter format fs=fat32 label="anything" (Label is optional)
```

The process can take some time, but the USB is mostly operational now, if not then go with Tetsujin advice and throw it away.

Comment: Hey Soul Spark, does that method delete all my data in the USB too?

Comment: Yes, but you wouldn't dream of having your only copy of any important data on something so easily damaged as a Flash key or SD card... would you?