# Is there anything else that I can try to recover my USB-Stick?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, partitioning

I have some corrupted USB-Sticks I want to recover. I am not experienced with this and wanted to wipe them to complete zero. So I mounted them in linux. The problem is it is in a "read-only" format. I know there's been tons of topics for that, but I couldn't find a solution in my case. I tried `chmod`and `rm` but I found out that it won't work since it's trying to write something to the USB-Stick. Then I tried gparted and It also didn't work.

I tried to wipe it with fsck, but when I try it the output is something like this:

```
...
writing 4 bytes at 4226572 failed: Operation not permitted
```

I also tried to zero it with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb`. But the Output is something like this:

```
dd: Can't open '/dev/sdb': Read-only file system
```

So is there anything else I can try which doesn't afford much time or can I throw it into the bin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only) Usually there is no fix. Throw it away.

Comment: Well Thank you. I kinda thought so.