# Memory card showing I/O device error in diskpart and write protected in disk management

Tags: hard-drive, usb, partitioning, disk-utility, micro-sd-card

I have a 
[Sandisk 16GB Class 10 Ultra MicroSD UHS-A1 Card with Adapter (SDSQUAR-016G-GO61A)](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07D2JS5WN/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1) 
memory card. I installed raspbian (Raspberry Pi OS) on it. It has been a few months since I used my Raspberry Pi. Yesterday, I tried to reinstall raspbian on the memory card. Diskpart is showing that the disk is not `readonly`. Yes, the diskpart is showing that the `readonly` property of the disk is not enabled, but when I tried disk checking, it says that the device is write-protected.

I couldn't format it. It was showing that the disk is write-protected. The things that I have tried:

1. Tried removing `readonly` attribute from diskpart which completes successfully but is of no use.
2. Using diskpart to clean the drive. It shows the error:

   `The request could not be performed because of an i/o device error.`
3. Tried error checking form disk properties which fails after giving the error:

   `The device is write protected.`
4. Tried formatting from disk manager and other disk management utilities. All of them failed with the error:

   `The request could not be performed because of an i/o device error.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)

Comment: I think the disk is not write-protected but the volumes are. I'll try removing attributes from volume and then post an update here