# Pen drive became write protected after using CrystalDiskMark 6

Tags: usb-flash-drive, write-protect

I used CrystalDiskMark 6 to benchmark my SanDisk pen drive but after benchmark my pen drive became write protected and no matter how much I try I could not get it back to normal. I have tried many of the solution , please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only) The usual solution is to throw it away & buy a new one.

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have tried removing the read only mode with cmd, formatting it with cmd and various other formatting software, lower level formatting and have also changed the policy on registry editor.

Comment: Tetsujin's answer covers the situation. There is nothing you can do beyond reading out any data you wish to keep.