# Can´t format, write nor delete files on a corrupted microSD card

Tags: windows-10, formatting, micro-sd-card, wipe

I have a SandDisk Ultra PLUS 16 GB microSD card
[(This exact model)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLaRK.png)
and I'm trying to format it without any luck so far.
It's the microSD card that I've using in my Android phone for 3 years without much trouble.

It currently has 7 GB aprox. of photos and music. I have all backed up so I don't mind destroying all the data. I plug it im my Windows 10 PC with an microSD-to-USB adapter. Haven't tried a microSD-to-SD adapter yet

I can't:

- Format the card
- Paste a file on it ==> "error 0x800703ee: The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid"
- Deleting a file while being plugged with USB cable and phone ==> "Device is write protected"

I've tried:

- Right click on the drive (F:) and formatting to FAT32 ==> Windows was unable to complete the format.
- Idem but with NTFS.
- Formatting from the phone ==> It says format complete but nothing has been deleted.
- Using EaseUS Partition Master ==> Can´t format nor wipe data, error pops up.
- Using Mini Tool ==> Idem.
- From cmd.exe running as Admin:

  - Using `chkdsk` and then `/f f:` ==> "The type of file system is RAW. Chkdsk is not available for RAW drives" despite having the FAT32 label in it's properties.
  - Using `disk part`, `attributes disk clear readonly` (to remove write protection) and then `clear` ==> "data error (cyclic redundancy check)"
- Using "FolderMount" app on my phone with ROOT privileges to solve both start-up detected problems as explained in [this video][2]
  [2]:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ep_-B_Eu6o and making another attempt at removing the write protection.

I don't know what else to try. I would probably have to buy another one but those things are not cheap here where I live and this case is really blowing my mind.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try: using any direct-access software (dmde or winhex, for example), open this SD as a device (not as a volume) and edit its first sector (sector 0) clearing its last two bytes from `55 AA` to `00 00`. Save this edition and exit program. Eject and re-plug SD, then try to init/format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)

Comment: I still can't save the changes when I edit the values. Changes won't remain when I eject and then plug it back..