# Pen Drive unaccessible

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, devicesanddrives

Hi guys my 64Gb Kingston flash drive has been in usage for about a year & I haven't had any problems so far using it for live disks and things like that until now.When i plug it in it appears in explorer for about 5 seconds & it disappears.I checked device manager and it says device descriptor request failed.

I tried opening it on my debian system and it appears in files for about a minute.when I try to open it I get a message box saying "Unable to access Kingston an operation is already pending".

Please help me with this issue as my pendrive is valuable to me .

Comment: Sounds very much like the pen drive has started to fail, if not failed completely. Just hope that you have a backup of whatever is on the flash drive, and move it all to a new one.

Comment: Well I dont have any important data but I need the drive badly

Comment: I hesitate to flag this is a dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only but in essence you have a failing drive. Trash it & get a new one. Flash drives are capricious. They will work until they don't. Once they start to fail, that's it; they're dead. Trash & replace immediately. *Golden Rule:* Never keep the **only** copy of any even vaguely important data on a disposable drive.