# Diskpart did not format or clean encrypted sdcard

Tags: formatting, diskpart, micro-sd-card

i have 64 gb sandisk sdcard that was encrypted using Bitlocker trying to format it within windows 10 home but that dose not work due to leack ability of windows 10 home edition.
then i moved my sdcard to anothet machine with windows7 as the following senario:
using Diskpart command i can view it and list all partitions i selected it tryied :clean all command but it says:diskpart encountred a problem :Access Denied!!
 i run all commands as an Administrator.
Any solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)

Comment: hi@Testsujin actually i tried all of these solutiin

Comment: Then it's time to throw it away. It's dead.