# Unable to mount usb drive after format (erasing it) in Catalina - disenter error

Tags: macos, mount, disk-utility, macos-catalina

I'm trying to create installer on an usb in Catalina (run createinstallmedia command).
The first step is to erase the disk. After the usb is erases, I get error "Could not mount disinter" error.

Also, if I erase the disk using Disk Utility I get the same error. 
After restart, I am able to use USB until I erase it.
It looks like something is preventing freshly formated disk to be mounted. 
This is company's computer and they might be running some software to prevent me from using USB.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: First test is to try another stick in the same computer & the same stick on another computer. Long-term, probably ref: http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only

Comment: I tried another USB with same result.