# Recover USB stick geometry

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning, disk-utility

I want to recover an USB stick with linux tools, the damage was caused by an incorrect disconnection of the drive. When the pen drive is connected in linux, there's no mounted fs.

I started the "trip" looking for the output in `dmesg`:

```
[  738.226184] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  741.572530] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  741.722069] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=3259
[  741.722074] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  741.722077] usb 1-7: Product: SM3259AA MEMORY BAR 
[  741.722080] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Silicon Motion,Inc. 
[  741.722860] usb-storage 1-7:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  741.723116] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-7:1.0
[  742.752857] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SMI      USB MEMORY BAR   1000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[  742.753591] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  742.756871] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Everything seems to be ok, but when I used `lsblk` the `sdc` drive is not shown. I repeated the `lsblk` command with the `-a` option (the option displays all the block devices even the empty ones), then the `sdc` drive appears but without information about it.

Then I used the `hdparam -g /dev/sdc` command to show its geometry:

```
/dev/sdc:
 geometry      = 1024/0/62, sectors = 0, start = 0
```

And I think the trouble is there. I supose the geometry follows the standard nomenclature `C/H/S`. Obviously the `hdparm -t /dev/sdc` command shows the "Timing buffered disk reads: read() hit EOF - device too small" message.

Then I went to know the original geometry of the device and use `hdparm -I /dev/sdc`:

```
/dev/sdc:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       *S`�Ccon Motion,Inc.
    Serial Number:      EMOMYRB RA  0100�
    Firmware Revision:      
    Media Serial Num:   2$XArd��������@� `��B�OOT����
    Media Manufacturer: ���������??����
    Transport:          Parallel; Revision: 0x0703
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0020) 
    Supported: 5 
    Likely used: 5
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   2   0
    heads       2560    0
    sectors/track   58  0
    --
    Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:         145 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:         152 MBytes 
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
    IORDY(may be)(cannot be disabled)
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Vendor
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 32  Current = ?
    DMA: not supported
    PIO: unknown
Integrity word not set (found 0x0000, expected 0xfea5)
```

I don't know why the strange (non-ASCII) characters in the information (the `dmesg` shows it correctly), but I see the "max" configuration and the current one (all in zero) and I think it could be recovered (I guess it).

There's a way to recover the USB stick? (the information inside is not important, it could be erased or overwrited).

**Note**: I tried to use `fdisk/sfdisk/testdisk` with no success because the medium is "not found".

Comment: It probably boils down to this - http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only - Quick test. Format it, in as simple a manner as you can [you could even try a different OS for this to dissociate from the current machine], write a file to it, eject, re-mount. If the file is still there then proceed with troubleshooting. If not, bin it.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think this is not the case of a write-protected drive, because of my research results. And another thing about is that the fs is not mounted (not even as read-only). I tested it in more than one machine, same results. And again, there's no way to write a file to it because the fs is not mounted as I writed in the question.

Comment: If the drive appears to be "_empty_" (akin to an optical drive having no disc in it), which appears to be the case here, then chances are you can't get the data back without professional help. You certainly shouldn't plan on ever using this memory stick again past recovering your data. Time to dig out your backups... Sorry!

Comment: @Attie I don't want to recover the data, I want to recover the drive. I think the same as you, i'ts like an optical drive without disk... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hence my 'simple test'. If it works, fine. If it doesn't, bin it & stop wasting effort. This type of memory is extremely fragile & once it starts to play up is simply not worth any effort. I used to get through literally thousands of these things for work, never saw one that was ever worth the fight once it started to play up.

Comment: @Tetsujin ok, I see your point, but I don't agree with it. I think that the correct answer could increase my knolegement about this and other drives management. I think here are professionals that had deal with this, if many of they can support and share they knoledge, I could try another options, and, even, could recover the drive. I think this, and SU, is not only an effort from-me to-me, it's a community effort that teachs and helps many others. And in a eco point of view (both ecological and economical), wasting things that could be working again I think it's not a wasting effort at all.

Comment: You could get the firmware chip replaced - that's what they do at specialist recovery labs. Again, absolutely not worth the effort [let alone cost] unless you have lost truly valuable data.