# Cannot format microSD card

Tags: linux, windows, macos, formatting, micro-sd-card

My microSD card I have used in a MavicMini drone does not work anymore. Last time it worked was before the drone's crash. The drone did not break, but the microSD card that was used in the drone acts weirdly.

Formatting the microSD seems to work, in the way there are no errors, but the data is not removed at all.
Checking for disk errors does not show any errors.

Creating directories and files in the disk's root works fine, but I cannot create subdirectories or files in other directories:

> [image]

The card size looks fine (64GB) and reading and writing data from the root of the card works fine.

Is there any hope to repair this microSD card so that I can use it?

---

I tried formatting on MavicMini, Windows 10, macOS, and Ubuntu 20.04, and none of them show any errors, but the data is not deleted (there are 6 videos before the drone's crash).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only) In short, it's probably toast. Bin it & get a new one.

Comment: @Tetsujin No, it's definitely not write-protected or read-only because I can create content in it.

Comment: Simple test. Format, add content. Eject, re-insert. Describe what has changed. Phantom content creation is a prime symptom of firmware lock.

Comment: @Tetsujin You are right... After some time, it simply goes back to the previous state (there are around 6 videos which work, but the files I have created after that are removed). However, I made sure that the physical lock is not enabled and checked the disk for errors like I mentioned already. Is there any hope to make it work again or it's simply a broken microSD now?

Comment: The firmware lock is to all intents & purposes irreversible. Just bin it & get another.