# USB Flash Drive not recognized after unsafe eject while dd was running

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, dd

Wasn't thinking I'm going to end up here.

### What happened?

I wanted to benchmark the speeds of a USB flash drive, which was USB 2.0. My system is `Debian bullseye/sid 5.8.7-1`. I used the same method which I use to benchmark my SSD:

```
# The USB drive was mounted and I went to it
$ cd <USB Flash drive>
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=tempfile bs=1M count=1024 conv=fdatasync,notrunc status=progress
```

I waited and waited, but no results came out. So I thought cancelling. I did an endless stream of CTRL + Cs on the terminal, no result. I tried to safely remove the usb, but it said it was in use. So, I've pulled out the USB drive. I tried the same commands again, same result: waited some time (~5 minutes) and nothing. This time I pressed a lot of CTRL + Cs + tried to kill the dd process (even with SIGKILL) + safely remove. Nothing worked, so, I've pulled out again the USB. Next time I plugged it in, it wasn't recognized nor auto-mounted, so I couldn't access it. And that's the problem.

### What I've tried?

1. Plugged the USB on Windows: it is not recognized in File Explorer (no volume is mounted when I plug the USB flash drive) and its capacity is 0MB. **Note:** The real capacity is 32GB. Photo: [USB in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlCQK.png)
2. Tried `mkusb` (based on this [article](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/restore-corrupted-usb-drive-to-original-state-in-linux)), but it says: "No suitable target device found". If I plug another USB flash drive, `mkusb` detects it.

### More details

- Output of `tail -f /var/log/messages` when I insert the drive:

```
Sep 17 16:08:08 Area51 kernel: [ 5241.197897] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
Sep 17 16:08:09 Area51 kernel: [ 5241.346189] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=ffff, idProduct=1201, bcdDevice= 0.00
Sep 17 16:08:09 Area51 kernel: [ 5241.346194] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Sep 17 16:08:09 Area51 kernel: [ 5241.347399] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Sep 17 16:08:09 Area51 kernel: [ 5241.347716] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
Sep 17 16:08:09 Area51 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 18: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3"
Sep 17 16:08:09 Area51 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 18 was not an MTP device
Sep 17 16:08:09 Area51 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 18: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3"
Sep 17 16:08:09 Area51 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 18 was not an MTP device
Sep 17 16:08:10 Area51 kernel: [ 5242.354414] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     NAND     USB2DISK         0.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
Sep 17 16:08:10 Area51 kernel: [ 5242.355049] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Sep 17 16:08:10 Area51 kernel: [ 5242.386958] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

- Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:57f5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 018: ID ffff:1201  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0b05:1854 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. ITE Device(8910)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c092 Logitech, Inc. G102 LIGHTSYNC Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This is the problematic flash drive: `Bus 001 Device 018: ID ffff:1201`

One thing to note it's that the USB flash drive now doesn't have it's vendor and product name.

Comment: Chances are you've killed it. They don't like being interrupted. See http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only for related info.

Comment: "One thing to note it's that the USB flash drive now doesn't have it's vendor and product name." - it's a firmware problem then, it's basically bricked.

Answer (score 0):

Get your hands on a low level format tool, then perform a low level format. After the LLF, create partition, and do a regular format. That should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you give me a link to such tool and also a tutorial on how to use it?

Comment: I think this one is probably the best one out there.
https://hddguru.com/software/HDD-LLF-Low-Level-Format-Tool/

Comment: I tried the tool: it doesn't even recognize my usb (I've also tried changing ports).

Answer (score 0):

This tool have rescued my flash drives ([link](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/6582-hp-usb-disk-storage-format-tool.html)) several times, when OS was unable to create partitions on device.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with the tool you mentioned, but no success. Photo: [HP Tool](https://imgur.com/YLJWskc)

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar problem, just that it was listed as 32 MB drive instead of 4 GB which it is.

used diskpart utility of windows to clear the readonly attribute.
Note : irrespective of whether your usb drive is set to read only or not, execute the attributes command to clear off the read only flag.

Then I used HP tool and this time the tool was able to format the drive and was detected as 4GB usb drive

Follow this link for Diskpart
https://www.howtogeek.com/740429/how-to-remove-write-protection-on-windows-10/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).