# Brand new SDcard not formatting (Mac)

Tags: raspberry-pi, formatting, disk-utility, micro-sd-card

Been pulling my hair out on this one.

Have a brand new Sandisk 32GB Extreme Plus SDCard. I've been trying to get an image on it to work (for my Raspberry Pi 4). When I bought it, I used balenaEtcher to flash HassOS (home assistant OS) on it.

When I plugged in my sdcard on my Rasperry Pi for the first time, I hooked my Pi up to a screen and saw the terminal text. There was some errors that popped up (I don't recall what it was, some Golang errors), so I thought to try and reflash the image.

I took it out, put it in my sdcard slot (on my CalDigit dock) and attempted to flash it again using BalenaEtcher. But I got a strange Checksum error. So I tried to format the SDCard, but I've been getting errors on everything I'm trying.

I've tried:
I've tried DiskUtility, [image: diskutility] and hitting "Erase" choosing various options (MSDOS-FAT) for example gives this error:

```
Formatting disk2s2 as MS-DOS (FAT) with name UNTITLED
512 bytes per physical sector
/dev/rdisk2s2: 49020 sectors in 12255 FAT16 clusters (2048 bytes/cluster)
bps=512 spc=4 res=1 nft=2 rde=512 sec=49152 mid=0xf8 spf=48 spt=32 hds=16 hid=67584 drv=0x80

Mounting disk
Could not mount disk2s2 after erase
```

And hassos-boot still remains!

I downloaded SDCardFormatter program to do a quick format, and get this error:

```
[ERROR] Invalid end of sector signature: 0xA940
[ERROR] fat_check_validate_boot_sector returned error: 22 (Invalid argument)
[ERROR] Initializing cached values failed: 22 (Invalid argument)
[ERROR] Generated invalid volume. fat_volume_create returned: 22 (Invalid argument)
```

I've tried Raspberry Pi Imager v1.5, and tried erasing the SDcard that way. And I get this error:

```
The chosen size is not valid for the chosen file system
```

I've tried
 `diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 MYDISK MBR disk2` and get this error: `Error: -69850: The chosen size is not valid for the chosen file system`

Tried ExFAT too instead of FAT32 (even though the disk is 32GB) and get this in logs:
`Formatting disk2s1 as ExFAT with name MYDISK Error: -69830: This operation requires an unmounted disk`

I bought a new SD card but it just blows my mind that a brand new SDCard would get screwed up already. Is there something else I should be trying?

Comment: *"Have a brand new Sandisk ..."* -- *"Brand new"* IMO really means untested.    *"And hassos-boot still remains!"* -- Sounds like the card has reverted to "permanent" write-protect mode.  Maybe you have a counterfeit card?

Comment: @sawdust What do you mean reverted to permanent write protect mode? What does that mean? I bought this at Microcenter (reputable electronics store around here). Box seems legit... Unsure how to know if it's counterfit for sure.

Comment: @sawdust you may be on to something, i just tried deleting the files on the sd card manually through Finder. They disappear, but when I eject the sdcard and put it back in they reappear. Weird!

Comment: I would recommend the app 'unetbootin' for making bootable devices from images.  I've had issues in the past with balena etcher on macos, for whatever reason.

Comment: Sounds like a classic case of the firmware write protect having kicked in; usually happens on a write error. See http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only The card is essentially trash now.

Comment: So I just got a new sdcard (from Amazon this time), plugged it in to SDcard reader on my CalDigit. Tried to flash again and it did the EXACT same thing (checksum error). I feel like i'm taking crazy pills. These are literally brand new cards. I'm starting to wonder if it's the sd card reader on my CalDigit screwing it up?