# What happens technically when a MicroSD (Secure Digital Storage Device) is not formattable, delectable, or reusable

Tags: sd-card, format, secure-erase

My question detected as a similar question, and the similar answer is to throw your SD in the garbage! I want to update my question by asking, what happens technically when a microSD card happens to act like that? It is totally readable, but not changeable, either delectable or formattable. It turned to a stone slab with carved data on it.
early question:
I recently trying to format and reuse a microSD card, which turned to "Secure Digital Storage Device" by an android phone 7.1 version. The data on the card is available and totally accessible but every moment I want to delete a folder it is automatically recovered. Even when I used it on the desktop, I did not insert it into the phone. Every possible solution in links like below turned out to not work. https://www.reneelab.com/secure-digital-storage-device.html

I used many ways to solve this issue, which provided with other websites, they all failed to work: Diskpart Format, Use the Registry. Please note that I don't want to use third-party software. please do not post solutions like that. I am curious how this card is so undeletable, I can use it for other purposes, and this discussion open for your explanation. but for now, I want a method to simply reuse my micro sd as an ordinary sd card.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWePb.jpg)

Comment: The underlying flash storage has become read-only. It is no longer usable. Replace it.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only might be a more detailed explanation

Comment: Essentially because one or more of the key blocks is no longer writeable it can no longer be updated to reflect changes in the device. Any writes essentially fail as a result.