# fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Read-only file system

Tags: usb, partitioning, read-only

When I try `mount /dev/sdb 1 /mnt/somewhere`, I get this:

```
mount: /mnt/somewhere: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

When I try `fdisk /dev/sdb`, I get this:

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Read-only file system
```

When I start `gparted` (with the USB plugged in) it loads forever,
but if I start it without the USB  plugged in, it loads fine.

If I run `lsusb` I get this:

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID abcd:1234 LogiLink UDisk flash drive
```

is there any way to fix this USB, or is it broken forever?

Comment: [Try run the badblocks command for verifying your flash driver for some *bad sector error*. Then run the following: *badblocks -w -s -o error.log /dev/sdb*. Maybe your one can be physically damaged if some badblock error's found and if so, it's not gonna can be fixed and even can be very dangerous keep your data on that device under risk of you to lost it forever.](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-check-the-physical-health-of-a-usb-stick-flash-drive/)

Comment: [Bad block error](https://www.petervis.com/gallery/hard/Hard%20Drive%20Basics/Bad%20Block%20Tables.html)

Comment: Try a deep format of the disk. But even if the disk will now seem to work, I wouldn't trust it in the future.

Comment: badblocks gives: `badblocks: Read-only file system while trying to open /dev/sdb`

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only

Answer (score -1):

use the command

run the command    `sudo gparted`

Then use Gpart to mount the drive

[image]