# 16 gb pendrive show few mb only how to fix it

Tags: usb-flash-drive, formatting

16 gb pendrive show few mb only how to fix it
The disk is write protected error whileformatting the
pendrives, memory sticks,external hard drive or SD Memory Card.

Comment: Another duplicate: [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)

Comment: Chances are the drive is dead. replace it. This is a common flash memory failure mode.