# Can't write to micro SD Card nor format it

Tags: formatting, sd-card, micro-sd-card, write-protect

I am using a 128GB micro sd card on my android phone, and i recently noticed that i could not write any files to it. Reading works fine.
I tried to format it using my windows computer, without success. Every file i remove reappears when i replug the micro sd in.
I tried following the steps in [this guide](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/sd-card-wont-format.html), with no success.

Do you have any idea on what i should do ? Please let me know in the comments if you need anything else.

Comment: i know this is a phone  [which is off topic here, though the computer r/w is not] but your card is dead, throw it away. See http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only for the long version of 'your card is dead, throw it away' ;))

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I guess I'll just backup everything and get a new one then..