# Trying to turn a bootable usb drive back to being non bootable

Tags: linux, windows-10, usb-flash-drive, iso-image, flashing

I am using Windows 10.

I used balenaEtcher to flash a usb drive with some Linux distro iso, but now I am trying to flash it with another iso and am failing:

[image]

I highly suspect this is because the USB drive is already flashed, thus I tried to "un-flash" like suggested in many internet guides, via Windows format options, again, with no success:

[image]

Who do I make this USB drive "regular" again, or, at the very least, make it possible to override the current flashed USB with another iso? (preferably using balenaEtcher, I prefer not to use any more 3rd party tools)

Comment: Being bootable is not something that prevents writing to the device. [Having failed is](https://superuser.com/q/1125282/432690). It may be your USB drive is beyond repair.

Comment: Try formatting it and not quick formatting it. Quick just zeros out entries in the FAT tables.

Comment: @avivgood2: If you have the `Linux` environment try to use `dd` command to erase the whole content of the USB drive: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M`. To find id of your USB drive you can use `sudo fdisk -l`. And then you can try to use your drive in the Windows. If after that it will not work then most likely you USB drive is destroyed.

Comment: @avivgood2: In the Windows environment you also can use `Diskpart` to wipe out (and format) the drive. [How to use DiskPart to clean and format drive not working on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-clean-and-format-storage-drive-using-diskpart-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following this guide to try and use DISKPART to fix the usb drive before giving up... (except maybe format as FAT32 instead of NTFS)
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-clean-and-format-storage-drive-using-diskpart-windows-10

commands are as follows (from the guide for posterity)

> Open Start. Search for Command Prompt, right-click the top result, and
> select the Run as administrator option. Type the following command to
> run DiskPart and press Enter:
>
> `diskpart`

---

> Type the following command to list all the active drives and press
> Enter:
>
> `list disk`

---

> Type the following command to select the drive that you want to clean
> and press Enter:
>
> `select disk DISK-NUMBER`
>
> In the command, replace DISK-NUMBER with the drive number you want to
> repair as it appears in the "Disk" column. **If you do not perform this
> step correctly, you could erase the wrong drive. Proceed with caution.**

---

> Type the following command to wipe out the drive and press Enter:
>
> `clean`

---

> Type the following command to confirm the drive still selected and
> press Enter:
>
> `lisk disk`
>
> Quick note: The output should include an asterisk (*) next to the
> selected drive.

---

> Type the following command to create a new partition and press Enter:
>
> `create partition primary`

---

> Type the following command to select the new primary partition and
> press Enter:
>
> `select partition 1`

---

> Type the following command to make the partition active and press
> Enter:
>
> `active`

---

> Type the following command to format the partition using the NTFS file
> system, set a drive label, and press Enter:
>
> `format fs=FILE-SYSTEM label=DRIVE-LABEL quick`
>
> In the command, replace FILE-SYSTEM with the name of the file system
> you want to use, such as NTFS or FAT32, and replace DRIVE-LABEL with
> the name of the drive as you want it to appear in File Explorer. The
> quick option is optional to perform a format more quickly. However, if
> you are not sure about the drive's condition, it is best to skip the
> option. Just remember that depending on the hard drive's size, the
> format could take a long time.
>
> This example formats the drive using the NTFS file system and names
> the partition "Data":
>
> `format fs=ntfs label=Data quick`

---

> Type the following command to assign a letter and make the drive
> available in File Explorer and press Enter:
>
> `assign letter=DRIVE-LETTER`
>
> In the command, change DRIVE-LETTER for the letter you want the drive
> to use, which is not assigned to another device.
>
> This example assigns the "G" letter:
>
> `assign letter=g`

---

> Type the following command to terminate DiskPart and press Enter:
>
> `exit`
>
> Type the following command to close Command Prompt and press Enter:
>
> `exit`

good luck!