# Faulty formatting leaves sd-card unusable. How to clear partitions?

Tags: partitioning, sd-card, testdisk

I have a sdxc with 64gb capacity, that was supposed to be re-purposed. And with some really bad luck, the machine formatting the sd card crashed mid-process.

I now have an sd card with 2 partitions:

1. 256mb Fat32 (boot)
2. 63gb primary

I can access, read and write the boot partition, but cannot see the 63gig one.

What fails is, formatting or modifying partitions.
I've tried all available windows system tools, as well as testdisk:

Here's the analyse output:

```
Disk \\.\PhysicalDrive2 - 63 GB / 59 GiB - CHS 7764 255 63
Current partition structure:
Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
Warning: number of heads/cylinder mismatches 64 (FAT) != 255 (HD)                                                      
Warning: number of sectors per track mismatches 32 (FAT) != 63 (HD)                                                      
1 P FAT32 LBA                0 130  3    33  37  4     524288 [boot]                                                                                                                                                                           
Bad relative sector.                                                                                                     
2 P Linux                   33  37  5  7764 108 24  124203008 [rootfs]                                                                                                                                                                         
Bad relative sector.                                                                                                    
No partition is bootable
```

Theoretically, clearing the partitions and the mbr works, yet shows no effect:

```
>[ Delete   ] Delete all data in the partition table
Clear MBR partition table by writing zero bytes to it? (Y/N)
Clear partition table, confirm ? (Y/N)
Partition table has been cleared.
You have to reboot for the change to take effect.
```

Once this is done I am re-mounting the media and nothing has happened.

At this point, I'm at a loss. What could be the issue and more importantly: how can I resolve it. The goal is to get a single 64gig partition back and to use it in a GoPro.

**Update**
I've now tried DiskGenius as well. The behavior is the same.
I can delete the partitions and save, yet after this step the partitions re-appear.

The same goes for copying a file to the "boot" partition. It is shown as created, yet after remounting it is gone again.

Comment: If it 'pretends' to do the operation but after eject/insert it didn't, the drive is toast. Firmware write protect has kicked in. You might try sending it back & claiming 'it was like that when I got it'. ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)

Comment: Or PC crashed due to issue with card while formatting? SD card may go read-only due to firmware decision.

Comment: Try deleting all partitions (volumes) using diskmgmt.msc or a third-party tool such as DiskGenius. Then format the entire free space as default, likely FAT32. You *might* try exFAT, but that might not work in some devices other than a PC with Windows (or Linux with fuse).

Comment: @Tetsujin "I can access, read and write the boot partition,"

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That has already happened multiple times. I've used all available system tool plus testdisk.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I've tried DiskGenius as well. Deleted both partitions. Partitions were "gone" on the UI. Hit Save and the partitions appeared again.

Comment: "I can access, read and write the boot partition," Are you certain? Save a new file to it then see if it's still there after re-mount. The firmware protect will not prevent read, btw, only write. Ghost writes are a definite symptom, which seems to be true of your attempts to re-write the partitioning.

Comment: You are right. The file is copied over, yet after remounting it is gone again. Essentially the same behaviour as with deleting partitions.

Comment: Then it's dead, I'm afraid.