# Diskpart clean: Not deleing anything, but says "DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk."

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, sd-card

I have an SD card that I can't seem to clean.

I'm running Win10, when inserting the SD Card Windows tells me to format the disk - but it always fails.
Using Disk Management I can (attempt to) delete a big chunk of the partition, but after a few seconds nothing happens and the Partitions stay the way they are.
Diskpart (see below) shows me the disks and their partitions, but neither clean, nor delete disk override have any effect - the terminal insists everything worked successfully, but the partitions stay the way they are. Can't convert it to MBR, nor override it with a tool like Rufus - Rufus will (attempt to) write to the disk, but to no avail.

Reinserting the card has no effect, neither do different machines.

[Diskpart output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/graW5.png)

Anybody have a clue, or am I sol?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only) [In short, the drive is dead. Bin it.]

Comment: 1. Remove *all* partitions, making it empty space. **Commit the action.** 2. Create a single partition. **Commit the action.** 3. Format the partition, likely FAT32. **Commit the action.** If Diskpart doesn't work, try a third-party tool such as free DiskGenius. If *that* doesn't work, the card is damaged.

Comment: Aight, guess I gotta bin it. Thankfully those things aren't expensive anymore.