# readonly preventing me form removing readonly on file

Tags: usb, file-permissions

So I recently tried to make a backup of my system (using veeam) to a USB drive but it crashed and now the USB drive seems to be corrupted.

I cant seem to fix it due to the files/drive/USB being `readonly`. I tried to remove `readonly` flag (from explorer properties), but I get the error "The media was protected".

What should I do? Is there any way to bypass the `readonly` attribute? I am not concerned about preserving the data on the USB drive.

Comment: You could try to reformat the disk.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only) [In short, the write error caused the firmware protection to kick in. The stick is now permanently read-only. Dead for all other uses except recovering what's on it.]

Comment: Dumb question, but have you actually tried to eject the usb using the normal eject method and then unplugging the drive, then plugging it back in? If a process keeps a lock on the file, it also is read only, buy ejecting the drive will always remove that lock.

Comment: I don't understand what prevents you from copying read-only files to some other drive.

Comment: Try in different PC. If that solves it issue is somewhere with PC (driver, setting or whatever). If it doesn't solve it the pendrive switched to read-only at firmware level. In which case it's best to bin it and get a new one.