# Resurrect a dead sd card

Tags: partitioning, sd-card

Looks like one of my SD Card is dead, however, I am struggling to resurrect it somehow.
First, there were some problems with car video recorder complaining that it can't write video to the card and can't format it.

I tried to format it with video recorder device but it failed and reported errors.

Then I tried to insert it into adapter and tried to format it using PC, but it also didn't work.

There were two kind of errors.

One error says that the disk is readonly and another error says it has bad sectors.

I tried to use AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition to Format it, Delete Partition but nothing worked.

When I tried to delete partition, it says

> Sorry, the current operation has been canceled! Information Code: 6
> Description:The partition table on the disk was failed to update as
> the partition table is being locked by other programs, please close
> other programs and retry.
>
> What does the Information Code mean? Please refer to:
> https://www.diskpart.com/help/errorcode.html

[image]

When I tried to format partition, it says

> Sorry, the current operation has been canceled! Information Code: 106
> Description:Failed to write FAT table 1 due to bad sectors.
>
> What does the Information Code mean? Please refer to:
> https://www.diskpart.com/help/errorcode.html

[image]

When I tried to check for bad sectors, all sectors where displayed as green.

[image]

On adapter I set to unlock. However, strange when I remove the adapter from the slot, the lock is getting in the middle position or in lock position.

Chkdsk doesn't work either.

Is my sd-card really dead or is there any way to get it alive?

My SD-card is Kingston 32 GB MicroSD. It was occasionally used I guess from around 2018 to 2023.

Comment: It's dead. Throw it away. See [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)

Comment: Try cleaning it with Isopropyl 99%?

Comment: @Arctiic Isopropyl 99%? Really? How that might help?

Comment: It's just a hail-Mary, in case there's an issue with the contacts being dirty, etc.  Might as well try everything if it's just bound for the graveyard otherwise, right?

Comment: well, I don't have isopropyl alcoloc; tried with Medical alcohol, but that didn't help

Answer (score 2):

All the operations fail because the drive can not be written to. Switching to a read-only state is a data protection mechanism built-in to many NAND flash based drives. This is a likely explanation for what you're observing here.

It is implemented at the firmware level so no amount of chkdsk-ing, DiskPart-ing etc. wil get around this. All such tools will report a read-only drive in some way.

The idea is you will still be able to rescue the data, you will however not be able to write new data to it. After the data is recovered, the drive should be decommissioned.

Comment: I don't really care about the data, it had only DVR video from the car driving...

Comment: also, if I decide it to be decommissioned, how should I do that properly? In Ukraine we don't really have different garbage bins (even if there are, when the truck arrives, it takes all the garbage altogether from all the trash bins), if I just throw it into a trash bin, it might pollute the trashpile environment.