# How can i fix RAW filesystem on microSD card?

Tags: windows, filesystems, memory-card

Suddenly yesterday afternoon my microSD card stopped working. It wasn't read by all my pc, except Chromebook (there was everything okay, but I will say more about that later).

On all my Windows machines I couldn't prepare this card to use, administrative Windows tools didn't work, even diskpart. It couldn't be successfully formatted, the letter couldn't be assigned, and the card was invisible in the system files explorer.

Only on Chromebook i could format this card and save/read files to/from there, it works fine, but not when I plugged it into a Windows machine. I don't have there important data, so I can do everything with it, but that card has a big capacity, so it is useful sometimes.

Comment: What filesystem do you use in Chromebook when you format the card?

Comment: You should remove all partitions etc in ChromeBook, then try creating a new one using specialised tools on a windows computer. Its likely that the card will only work on windows or chromebook, but not both.

Comment: Perhaps it's using a file system Windows doesn't support.  Try examining with a more flexible third-party tool such as DiskGenius, https://www.diskgenius.com/

Comment: Your SD card is dead. This is a normal set of symptoms of a dead SD card.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)