# I guess there is just no fixing the "SanDisk cruzer glide 64GB" USB 'write protection'

Tags: usb

I've tried for months to un-'write protect' this drive("cruzer glide 64GB"). searched and performed all remedies with no success. I've already backed up the drive but wanted, so badly, to beat this problem. I have done this about a year ago and wanted to see if there were any new fixes, now.

tried reformating through windows(including safe mode). windows says write protected.

tried registry. It performs the task but when done it's still locked.

tried a program (MiniTool Partition Wizard Free Edition) that said it would remove the write protection. but there are no options to choose from when I highlight the drive in question because IT IS WRITE PROTECTED...

tried "advanced systemcare" to try to 'shred file', it goes through a process, like it's working, only to say 'failed' at the end.

every site is confident that it can be fixed, but it can't.
I wanted to just add this comment to a post on the same issue, but this site wouldn't let me...
I guess the only thing left to do is to throw it in the burn barrel. I have been defeated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only) [In short, yes, throw it away.]

Comment: The disk has probably failed and the firmware has set it to read-only. This disk is most likely dead.

Comment: A [new 64GB drive is £10.50](https://www.amazon.co.uk/SanDisk-SDCZ60-064G-B35-Cruzer-Glide-Flash-Black-Red/dp/B007YX9OA8). It is worth less than a tub of cinema popcorn.