# My Sandisk Ultra USB 3.0 32GB flash drive won't decrypt

Tags: windows-10, usb, security, encryption, decryption

I am running Windows 10 Pro 64.

For some reason my
Sandisk Ultra USB 3.0 32GB flash drive will not decrypt. It’s the whole drive that was encrypted I think.

Its stopped working in VeraCrypt 1.26.7 it says “VeraCrypt not responding.” It’s normally G: drive its showing in Device Manager though.

I tried removing and reinstalling VeraCrypt but still get same error.

Any ideas thanks?

Comment: If the drive is corrupt, fort whatever reason, that tends to happen. Nothing to do with Veracrypt, obviously.

Comment: Hopefully, you have data stored elsewhere. If *part* of a file system is corrupt, it is often possible to salvage some data. If the *whole drive* is encrypted, though, it's unlikely anything can be saved from it. You might try using another PC to decrypt, on the off-chance that there is some issue with USB settings in the Registry of the first PC, but don't expect success.  When you're done trying to salvage data, see if the drive failed: remove the partition, reformat and test it.

Comment: The USB flash drive is damaged and VeraCrypt can’t read it. Thus it  can’t be decrypted.

Comment: Yes, I would agree, the device is indeed the reason it can’t be mounted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only)