# What is the mechanism behind SD card's write-protection under MS Windows and how to deactivate it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, sd-card, write-protect

I have an SD card which I use in Canon EOS 700D camera. I cannot delete the files! I checked the basic things I know the operating system is using for this purpose:

1. The physical lock on the side of the SD card is not locked (it is shifted to the "upward" position).
2. The read-only attribute of the individual files was not set.
3. I notice that there is a read-only attribute set for directories - see this screenshot:
   [image]

   When I turn it off, it gives an error "media is write protected":

   [image]

   What is this "write protection", what mechanism is behind it, where it is driven from? I click "ignore" and finally can delete the files. However, eject (unmount) the SD card and mount it again, it is set again!
4. I run `cmd` as Administrator, and run `diskpart` in it, it says "Current Read-only State : Yes", but I can't seem to turn it off:

   ```
   Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3693]
   (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

   C:\WINDOWS\system32>diskpart

   Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.19041.3636

   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
   On computer: LAPTOP-SAAK4JMO

   DISKPART> list disk

     Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
     --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
     Disk 0    Online          953 GB      0 B        *
     Disk 1    Online           59 GB  1024 KB
     Disk 2    No Media           0 B      0 B

   DISKPART> select disk 1

   Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

   DISKPART> attributes disk
   Current Read-only State : Yes
   Read-only  : No
   Boot Disk  : No
   Pagefile Disk  : No
   Hibernation File Disk  : No
   Crashdump Disk  : No
   Clustered Disk  : No

   DISKPART> attributes disk clear readonly

   Disk attributes cleared successfully.

   DISKPART> attributes disk
   Current Read-only State : Yes
   Read-only  : No
   Boot Disk  : No
   Pagefile Disk  : No
   Hibernation File Disk  : No
   Crashdump Disk  : No
   Clustered Disk  : No

   DISKPART>
   ```

   Why wasn't dispart able to set the `Current Read-only State` to `No`?
5. Further information from the `diskpart` on the volume, as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only), says that the volume's status is "healthy", and shows no read-only flag:

   ```
   DISKPART> list volume

     Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
     ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
     Volume 0     C   WINDOWS      NTFS   Partition    120 GB  Healthy    Boot
     Volume 1     D   DATA         NTFS   Partition    814 GB  Healthy    Pagefile
     Volume 2         SYSTEM       FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
     Volume 3         WINPE        FAT32  Partition    512 MB  Healthy    Hidden
     Volume 4         Onekey       NTFS   Partition     18 GB  Healthy    Hidden
     Volume 5         WinRE        NTFS   Partition   1024 MB  Healthy    Hidden
     Volume 6     E   Nový svazek  exFAT  Removable     59 GB  Healthy
     Volume 7     F                       Removable       0 B  No Media

   DISKPART> select volume 6

   Volume 6 is the selected volume.

   DISKPART> detail volume

     Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
     --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
   * Disk 1    Online           59 GB  1024 KB

   Read-only              : No
   Hidden                 : No
   No Default Drive Letter: No
   Shadow Copy            : No
   Offline                : No
   BitLocker Encrypted    : No
   Installable            : Yes

   Volume Capacity        :   59 GB
   Volume Free Space      : 2504 MB
   ```
6. The `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies` registry key doesn't exist.

**MAIN OVERALL QUESTION:** I am totally confused why and how is this possible? What particular mechanism of the Windows operating system is doing this? Is it somewhere on the SD card filesystem (the card has exFAT filesystem)? Is it a standard mechanism of that particular filesystem? If not, why does Windows respect that?

Comment: The SD card could have failed. Many go read-only when they go bad so that you can copy data off them before replacing them. This happens in the controller on the card.

Comment: @Mokubai thanks. 1) The system literally recognizes that there is write protection. So no matter the original cause, it must have been set somehow and must work somehow. That's what I am asking. 2) How do I recognize whether the cause of it is that the card went bad? 3) Seems unlikely because other card is doing the same. It is more likely that it is the Canon Camera doing this protection from deletion, however, I am asking and looking for a solution from the PC/Windows/filesystem perspective.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to try it in a card reader away from the camera to prove whether it is the card or camera.

Comment: @Tomas, the probability camera set SD to R/O is minimal. As you get explained this is (with high probability) prefailed card. Copy the files and replace it with new card, do not forget these cards are consumables.

Comment: [ I click "ignore" and finally can delete the files] does not sound plausible to me... Is the write-protect switch fully in the correct position? If I remember correctly, it's read by a sensor inside your reader (not by the card itself). Does this happen with a different reader?

Comment: @Tomas, moreover seems like you use this card as long term storage which is NOT advisable! This card is created five years ago and seems like never formatted.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the link, but it doesn't answer my question. I have tried some of the solutions proposed here but it failed (added them as points 5. and 6. to my question). I would appreciate if we can keep my question open with the particularities of my report. Thanks!

Comment: @Mokubai I am indeed using a USB card reader to connect this SD card to PC. I am not doing it via camera. At this moment, I don't have a different card reader to try. However, the card reader is generally working fine, I don't expect problem there.

Comment: If you do ignore the warning and delete a file, does that file reappear when you eject and reinsert the card?

Comment: @Mokubai no, the deleted files do not reappear.

Comment: @Testujin I asked you to not close this question, to keep the particularities of my situation, and I told you it doesn't answer it!!! I invested so much time and effort in formulating it! Thanks for wasting all my efforts to get help. Really helps to make this a great site!

Comment: @harrymc same to you. You could use the question closing for people who **don't** take the effort, who don't look at those similar questions. Wasn't my case.

Comment: @Tomas question closure requires three votes ... also,  you cannot assume that either of these people voted to close ...  if you do not agree with a closure, then update your question with an explanation why it should be reopened and request it to be reopened

Comment: @jsotola in this case the question was closed by someone with a [gold tag badge in the windows tag](https://superuser.com/help/badges/52/windows) which requires only a single vote. Since my questions had been answered I was not convinced it was exactly the same problem hence I had not applied a vote which in my case as a moderator would also be a single binding vote.

Comment: @Mokubai it still comes down to the fact that questions are not closed on a whim, and have a mechanism for reopening