# SD Memory Card (SDXC) is not possible format after error in writing files

Tags: sd-card

I bought a few days ago new SD Memory Card 512 GB MicroSDXC 512GB EVO Plus which was formatted in ExFAT and today I transferred some video files into SD card but during the process of writing files was some error then I am not not able format or do something with files (rename, delete, etc).

So it seems that now the SD card is read only.

If I want delete, rename, format, etc some files or SD card then SD Card is unmounted. I also tried some another formatting methods but it is same. I also tried application like SD Card Formatter but after a few seconds I got this message:

> "Formatting failed. Unable to complete format. Reinsert the card and format again".

Do you think it is possible fix this issue or it is wasting of time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if my USB flash drive is write-protected or read-only?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only) [Best guess, fake SD card - once you write past where data areas actually exist, it fails. Send it back.] How much did it cost?